# How to store values from a for loop into a session in php, so I can access them individually?

Tags: php, session, for-loop

I am trying to store the values of `"rand".$i` and the values of `"fontr".$i` in a session or something else so I can access them in the next page, and I need to access them by using `fontr1, fontr2 ...` and `rand1, rand2 ...` as names.

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=$rand;$i++)
{ ?>

<input type=text name=rand<?=$i?> value=" <?php $var1="rand".$i; if(isset($_POST[$var1])) {echo $_POST[$var1]; } else {echo "Rand".$i;} ?> " size=15><BR>

<select name="fontr<?=$i?>">
<?php $var3="fontr".$i; ?>
<option value='Fonts/arial.ttf' <?php if(isset($_POST[$var3]) && $_POST[$var3]=='Fonts/arial.ttf') echo 'selected="selected"'?> >Arial</option>
<option value='Fonts/comic.ttf' <?php if(isset($_POST[$var3]) && $_POST[$var3]=='Fonts/comic.ttf') echo 'selected="selected"'?> >Comic Sans</option>
</select>

<?php } ?>
```

I know how to store a value in a session like this

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['culoaresup']))
$_SESSION['culoaresup'] = $_POST['culoaresup']; ?>


 if(isset($_POST['Vizualizeaza']))
 $_SESSION['rand'] = $rand;
```

But I don't know how to store values from a for loop that I can access individually.

Hope you can understand me.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
for($i=1;$i<=$rand;$i++)
{
   $_SESSION['rand'.$i] = $_POST['rand'.$i];
   $_SESSION['fontr'.$i] = $_POST['fontr'.$i];

   echo $_SESSION['rand'.$i]." ".$_SESSION['fontr'.$i]."<br/>";   
}
```

The way you retrieve the value is the same like for loop for your input and select.
One more thing, you have to past the $rand value so that the for loop for retrieve the data will loop until the last data that you have.

Just try run this code to see the result.

Comment: yes, but in the next page can I do something like this : for($i=1;$i<=$rand;$i++)
{
   $_POST['rand'.$i]=$_SESSION['rand'.$i] ;
    $_POST['fontr'.$i]=$_SESSION['fontr'.$i];

   echo $_POST['rand'.$i]." ".$_POST['fontr'.$i]."<br/>";   
} ?

Comment: yes you can but your code must inside form tag <form method="post" action="result.php">....</form>

Comment: why would you assign the session variable to a post variable in the next page? you should simply use the session variable itself. Check out my answer and see if it's simplier to understand

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   session_start();

   for($i = 0;$i < $rand; $i++) { 
?>
    <input type="text" name="rand[]" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION[$i][0])) {
            echo $_SESSION[$i][0]; 
        } else {
            echo "Rand" . ($i + 1);
        } ?> " size="15"><BR>

    <select name="fontr[]">
        <option value="Fonts/arial.ttf" <?php 
              if(isset($_SESSION[$i][1]) && $_SESSION[$i][1]=='Fonts/arial.ttf') 
                 echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Arial</option>
        <option value="Fonts/comic.ttf" <?php 
              if(isset($_SESSION[$i][1]) && $_SESSION[$i][1]=='Fonts/comic.ttf') 
                 echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> >Comic Sans</option>
    </select>

<?php 
   } 
?>
```

After you submit the form you can have:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['rand']); $i++) {
        $_SESSION[$i][0] = $_POST['rand'][$i]; // store the rand
        $_SESSION[$i][1] = $_POST['fontr'][$i]; // store the fontr
    }
?>
```

You can also define it separately like

```
$_SESSION['rand' . $i] = $_POST['rand'][$i]
```

and you can call it then with `$_SESSION['rand0']` or you can simply create a new variable like

```
${'rand' . $i} = $_POST['rand'][$i];
echo $rand0;
```

I also hope you understand me :)

Comment: Ma bucur ca pot ajuta o conationala.. esti o raritate pe-aici :))

Comment: Am inteles ce faci, dar eu am incercat sa fac ceva ca primul raspuns , doar ca imi adaug cate un isset ca sa verific daca e introdusa sau nu valoarea. Ideea e ca nu merge in pagina urmatoare. Adica nu mi a mers. o sa incerc acum cu raspunsul tau

Comment: Trebuie sa pui `session_start()` la inceputul fiecarei pagini unde folosesti sesiuni.